# Por qué no se carga captcha

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

No puedo navegar usar el motor Google por dos motivos principales: 1 es que directamente bloquea todas mis búsquedas con mensajes como "Esta conexión no es privada" o "Esta conexión no es segura" "El certificado no es válido" etc y 2 no aparece el captcha para poder tildarlo.
Sí puedo usar Bing o DuckDuck u otros, pero entonces nunca se carga ningún captcha como "No soy un robot" para poder marcarlo y por lo tanto no puedo continuar, no puedo ingresar a niguna página, a ningún sitio.
Hice absolutamente todo lo indicado en todos los foros y por todos los expertos:
Borré todos los temporales,
Borré todas las coockies y todos los historiales.
Desinstalé y reinstalé Ópera, Google y Mozilla.
Desinstalé mis antivirus McAfee Total Protection Y GrdinSoft Antimalware.
Reinicié y descargué y actualicé todos mis navegadores.
Probé usando las páginas de incógnito.
Nada funciona. La ventanita captcha para tildar no aparece.
Ahora no puedo reinstalar mis antivirus porque en sus sitios piden completar el captcha para ingresar: pero resulta que no aparece.
Si tienen una solución por favor se las agradeceré.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a [ES.so], por favor lee [ask] ya que tu pregunta no concuerda con la temática del sitio, de paso haz el [tour]

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Puedes probar a borrar la caché de esa página web en la Configuración de Google Chrome. Puede que no se solucione pero nunca está de más intentarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: Hola Adrián: Como ya expliqué probé todo incluso después de desinstalar todos mis antivirus y todos los navegadores repetí la limpieza y nada sirve. Evidentemente el motor Google comanda todo, bloquea todas mis búsquedas y nadie sabe ni por que ni como solucionarlo en ningún foro de ningún lado